# google.maps.event.addListener for tilesloaded suddenly not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, addeventlistener

While on my cordova/ionic app today, testing popover messages I compiled my app and suddenly the maps aren't loading...just my custom "Loading map..." spinning icon keeps showing.

I dive deeper and see that

```
var setMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapBody"), mapOptions) ;
```

is in fact loading - I am able to print `setMap` to console.

I have a function that calls itself every 500ms checking for `tilesloaded` has completed to then stop the spinner and the map will naturally load.

However, `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(setMap,'tilesloaded', function() {..}` never fires.

Never seen this before...it started happening at the same time on both iOS and on Android - and I wasn't touching any of the mapping code when this just suddenly started.

code:

```
  $scope.mapLoader = 0 ;
  $scope.mapTrigger = 0 ;
  function checkLoader() {
    if ($scope.mapLoader == 0) {
      //console.log(setMap) ;
      if (setMap && $scope.mapTrigger == 0) {
        console.log("setMap/mapTrigger") ;
        console.log(setMap) ;
        $scope.mapTrigger = 1 ;
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(setMap,'tilesloaded', (function() {
          ////// it never makes it inside here, as the function never fires.
          console.log("tilesloaded done") ;
          $scope.mapLoader = 1 ;
          $scope.$apply() ;
        });
      setTimeout(function() {
        //console.log("Checking Loader") ;
        checkLoader() ;
      },500) ;
    } 
  }

  if ($scope.mapLoader == 0) {
    checkLoader() ;
  } else {
    $scope.mapLoader = 1 ;
  }
```

So, set map is loading, and it looks like the `tilesloaded` is complete (from the console log below)...yet the addListenerOnce isn't firing.  Which to some degree makes sense, because the map doesn't load...and the inner addListenerOnce function never fires.  I get no errors, no google errors...nothing.

console.log output:

```
setMap/mapTrigger
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Well, it turns out adding a css tag for a popover window and NOT closing the element will allow your app to work but NOT google maps.

```
.platform-ios ion-popover-view.fit {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
```

Should be:

```
.platform-ios ion-popover-view.fit {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Guess I have been staring at the screen too long and am starting to make "Need to call it a day" mistakes.